# How do i restrict the user only to read the entities, if I am using remote api?

Tags: google-app-engine

Here I am using remote api to access the datastore, and the user is having "viewer" permission, and he is able to write, update, delete the entities, even though he is having "viewer" permission.

Is there any way that I can restrict this user only to read the entities, if I am using remote api ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. Don't provide remote_api access to untrusted users.